# init not called with valid version with facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I use code from facebook for developer to build a login, and I tried to use code on it to logout. An error appeared. Then I found a solution to solve that problem and in the end come into the problem below. I am new in Javascript, please give me some detailed help. Thank you so much!
`init not called with valid version`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>User</title>
</head>
<script>

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '**************',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                          // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v3.2' // use graph api version 2.8
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


    function logout() {
        FB.logout(function (response) {
            // user is now logged out
        });
    }


</script>

<body>

<div class='container'>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" onclick="logout();">log out</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you actually use a correct app id, or are there really just *-signs in your code? btw, it is safe to share an app id, it would be in the client code anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I do use a correct app id.